# Show Outlook downloads by time downloaded, not time received

Tags: download, microsoft-outlook, microsoft

This questions is partially Outlook related and partially Microsoft Windows related. I often download and open email attachments on Outlook from work, but not immediately after receiving them. Or I may re-download a file from an email. However, in my 'downloads' folder on file explorer, the download date/time will be when the email with attachment was received, not when it was downloaded.

Let's say I receive an email Tuesday at 3pm and download a file from it Wednesday at 4pm. On file explorer, if I sort by 'date modified' the file modified date will be Tuesday at 3pm. I want the date modified to be Wednesday at 4pm so it's right there at the top. Is there a way to do this? Extremely frustrating when I re-download old attachments and then have to search for the name in the downloads list (long story short, lots of oddly named files).

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test and research on this case, i'm afraid the download time could not be set as the file modified time.